# mapped false in form with Symfony 3

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have a problem with my application server. The server is under PHP, Symfony 3. I have the following form in my controller:

```
public function addAction($id, Request $request)
{
    if (!$request->isMethod("POST")) {
        $response = new JsonResponse("POST only");
        $response->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
        return $response;
    }

    if ($id != 0) {
        $cr = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Cr')->find($id);
    } else {
        $cr = new Cr();
    }

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($cr, array('csrf_protection' => false))
        ->add('date', DateType::class, array(
                'required' => true,
                'widget' => 'single_text',
            )
        )
        ->add('description', TextareaType::class, array('required' => true))
        ->add('todo', TextareaType::class, array('required' => true))
        ->add('typeVisite', IntegerType::class, array('required' => true))
        ->add('project', IntegerType::class, array('mapped' => false))
        ->getForm();

    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        $form->submit($request->request->get($form->getName()));

        if ($form->isValid()) {

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

            $em->persist($cr);

            $this->updateMobilisationHebdo($cr);
            $this->updateSuiviBenevoles($cr);
            if (isset($request->request->get($form->getName())['project']) && $cr->getTypevisite() != 0) {
                $this->updateSuiviproject($cr, $request->request->get($form->getName())['project']);
            }

            $em->flush();

            return new JsonResponse('ok');
        } else {
            $errors = [];
            foreach ($form->getErrors(true, true) as $error) {
                $errors[] = $error->getOrigin()->getName() . ' : ' . $error->getMessage();
            }

            $response = new JsonResponse($errors);
            $response->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
            return $response;
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that if I select a project existing for the field `project`, it does not take ID of this one, but stay by default in 0.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Is a project another entity in your system? If you're using Doctrine ORM, that would map that relationship and the form would allow them to select an id that corresponds to the project. I assume you're manually creating a `select` or something on the display side that has your project list?

Comment: Also, the Sensio Framework Bundle gives you a [`@Method('POST')` annotation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html#route-method) which should obviate the need to manually check the method.

Comment: Yes, "project" is another entity of my system. And yes actually, I have on the side of the display a way to select a project among a list

Comment: Try to use the [`EntityType`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html) instead of manually curating it. Also, `dump()` is your friend; check that your values are getting through and set at various points in the request and response.